# BOOST_FOREACH enters infinite loop when using "break"?

Tags: c++, boost, c++03

The following code segment enters an infinite loop inside the
`BOOST_FOREACH` statement, and I can't figure out why.  As far as I can
tell from the Boost documentation, it should be fine to use "break"
inside a `BOOST_FOREACH` loop.  Any idea what might be going wrong here?

```
std::vector<std::wstring> sectors = getSectors();
if (!_sectorCodes.empty()) {  // _sectorCodes is a std::set<std::wstring>.
    bool ok = false; // did we find the sector code we wanted?
    BOOST_FOREACH(Symbol sector, sectors) {
        if (_sectorCodes.find(sector) != _sectorCodes.end()) {
            ok = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!ok) return NULL;
}
```

If I replace the `BOOST_FOREACH` loop with a for loop (using an iterator
from `sectors.begin()` to `sectors.end()`), then it works just fine (no
infinite loop).

Versions & additional info:

- Boost: 1.40.0
- gcc: 4.1.2
- architecture: x86_64
- I only get this behavior for release builds; if I do a debug build, then it works as expected.
- When compiled under visual studio, it works as expected -- i.e., no infinite loop.

In response to mkb's question, here's what I get when I run `gcc -E`:

```
if (!_sectorCodes.empty()) {
 bool ok = false;
 if (boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_t _foreach_col148 = boost::foreach_detail_::contain( (sectors) , (true ? 0 : boost::foreach_detail_::or_( boost::foreach_detail_::and_( boost::foreach_detail_::not_(boost::foreach_detail_::is_array_(sectors)) , (true ? 0 : boost::foreach_detail_::is_rvalue_( (true ? boost::foreach_detail_::make_probe(sectors) : (sectors)), 0))) , boost::foreach_detail_::and_( boost::foreach_detail_::not_(boost_foreach_is_noncopyable( boost::foreach_detail_::to_ptr(sectors) , boost_foreach_argument_dependent_lookup_hack_value)) , boost_foreach_is_lightweight_proxy( boost::foreach_detail_::to_ptr(sectors) , boost_foreach_argument_dependent_lookup_hack_value)))))) {} else if (boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_t _foreach_cur148 = boost::foreach_detail_::begin( _foreach_col148 , (true ? 0 : boost::foreach_detail_::encode_type(sectors, boost::foreach_detail_::is_const_(sectors))) , (true ? 0 : boost::foreach_detail_::or_( boost::foreach_detail_::and_( boost::foreach_detail_::not_(boost::foreach_detail_::is_array_(sectors)) , (true ? 0 : boost::foreach_detail_::is_rvalue_( (true ? boost::foreach_detail_::make_probe(sectors) : (sectors)), 0))) , boost::foreach_detail_::and_( boost::foreach_detail_::not_(boost_foreach_is_noncopyable( boost::foreach_detail_::to_ptr(sectors) , boost_foreach_argument_dependent_lookup_hack_value)) , boost_foreach_is_lightweight_proxy( boost::foreach_detail_::to_ptr(sectors) , boost_foreach_argument_dependent_lookup_hack_value)))))) {} else if (boost::foreach_detail_::auto_any_t _foreach_end148 = boost::foreach_detail_::end( _foreach_col148 , (true ? 0 : boost::foreach_detail_::encode_type(sectors, boost::foreach_detail_::is_const_(sectors))) , (true ? 0 : boost::foreach_detail_::or_( boost::foreach_detail_::and_( boost::foreach_detail_::not_(boost::foreach_detail_::is_array_(sectors)) , (true ? 0 : boost::foreach_detail_::is_rvalue_( (true ? boost::foreach_detail_::make_probe(sectors) : (sectors)), 0))) , boost::foreach_detail_::and_( boost::foreach_detail_::not_(boost_foreach_is_noncopyable( boost::foreach_detail_::to_ptr(sectors) , boost_foreach_argument_dependent_lookup_hack_value)) , boost_foreach_is_lightweight_proxy( boost::foreach_detail_::to_ptr(sectors) , boost_foreach_argument_dependent_lookup_hack_value)))))) {} else for (bool _foreach_continue148 = true; _foreach_continue148 && !boost::foreach_detail_::done( _foreach_cur148 , _foreach_end148 , (true ? 0 : boost::foreach_detail_::encode_type(sectors, boost::foreach_detail_::is_const_(sectors)))); _foreach_continue148 ? boost::foreach_detail_::next( _foreach_cur148 , (true ? 0 : boost::foreach_detail_::encode_type(sectors, boost::foreach_detail_::is_const_(sectors)))) : (void)0) if (boost::foreach_detail_::set_false(_foreach_continue148)) {} else for (Symbol sector = boost::foreach_detail_::deref( _foreach_cur148 , (true ? 0 : boost::foreach_detail_::encode_type(sectors, boost::foreach_detail_::is_const_(sectors)))); !_foreach_continue148; _foreach_continue148 = true) {
  if (_sectorCodes.find(sector) != _sectorCodes.end()) {
   ok = true;
   break;
  }
 }
 if (!ok) return PatternFeatureSet_ptr();
}
```

One notable feature of this expansion is that there are two nested for loops.  I'm not able to figure out what's going on in the inner vs outer loops, but is it possible that (as David suggests) I'm breaking out of just the inner loop, and BOOST_FOREACH isn't handling that quite right for some reason?

Comment: Why not use the c++11 range for loop instead?

Comment: I have external constraints that restrict which compiler versions I can use, including multiple architectures; and unfortunately that means I can't use c++11; I'm stuck with using c++98.

Comment: c++98 or c++03? ok, I missed the compiler's version. it is c++03

Comment: This sounds like an optimizer bug to me, try using a newer version of GCC and see if the problem goes away. or if this isn't possible, try finding out if a specific optimization causes this problem and try disabling it for the file

Comment: I don't know about the rules for `BOOST_FOREACH`, but if you use anything with "for each" in its name, and then use a break to leave the loop, you're lying to the reader.

Comment: @VJovic sorry, you're  right -- I meant c++03.

Comment: Out of curiosity what happens if you run this through `gcc -E` (which should stop after preprocessing)?

Comment: @EdwardLoper: thanks for the preprocessor output, unfortunately it's not helping much because the issue is more probably due to optimizations... would it be LLVM I would have asked for the IR, but with gcc we will have to make do with the assembly I fear. You can use `-S` to dump the assembly generated. If you can isolate the issue in as small a function as you can before doing so it would be great, and then give us the assembly listing of that function (with optimizations on)... and perhaps that a few veterans x86 assembly hackers will spot the issue there.

Comment: @James Kanze Could the same not be said of any loop with a break in it? The keyword inherently means that the loop's stated end condition is circumvented.

Comment: @Slavik81 It could be, and in fact, I never use `break` except to end the case of a switch.  But such use is, regrettably, ubiquitous; presumably, part of the motivation of `for_each` is to expression clearly that the loop does execute for each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet that simplifying the function:

```
std::wstring const* find(std::vector<Symbol> const& sectors) {
    if (!_sectorCodes.empty()) {
        BOOST_FOREACH(Symbol sector, sectors) {
            std::set<Symbol>::const_iterator it = _sectorCodes.find(sector);
            if (it != _sectorCodes.end()) { return &*it; }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
} // find
```

solves the issue.

Although with optimizations, it's hard to know... but at least your code will be more readable. I don't have your version of gcc to test though, and never had any trouble with mine (or clang), so I can only suggest :x

Comment: Well, this code block is in the middle of a function (i.e., I don't just return the result, but do other things with it), so I'd need to add a helper function to do that -- but that's probably the right thing to do.  But the main issue I have is not with this particular case, but with whether I can trust BOOST_FOREACH to do what I expect it to.

Comment: @EdwardLoper: you can trust `BOOST_FOREACH` but can you trust your compiler... that is another question :x

Comment: Too true.  But usually I can trust boost to properly deal with and mask the foibles of my compiler. :)